# How to get change the package name without using eclips

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I was lose my android project and i was just only the apk file which is only on publish on google play store.my quation is that any kinde of formula or trick is available to get my source code and i was change the package name and uploade it again..

Comment: You can do reverse engineering to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these free programs...

1. http://www.xda-developers.com/android/easily-decompile-and-recompile-apks-with-android-apktool/
2. **Dex2jar**

Answer (score 0):

**Android .apk file is a compressed form of a file which contains only Java classes (*in .dex form)*, xml files**.

To get the source code from apk file, you can use tools like

1. [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)
2. [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.4.1.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)

You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file) link for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do reverse engineering, but you will not get the exact source code. Because as google announce that whenever you upload apk to market google play runs a proguard on it so whenever anybody try to reverse engineering no body can exact code. It makes your class name Like class A, class B and for loop converts to while  loop and and change the variable name to unreadable form.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through it, it gives you all the resources and source code of application. Now you are free to change the package name and so on..

**`Procedure for decoding .apk files, step-by-step method:`**

**`Step 1:`**

Make a new folder and put .apk file in it (which you want to decode). Now rename the extension of this `.apk` file to `.zip` (eg.: rename from filename.apk to filename.apk.zip) and save it.

If problems in the converting into .zip please refers [`link`](http://www.mediacollege.com/microsoft/windows/extension-change.html)

After getting .zip now you get classes.dex files, etc. At this stage you are able to see drawable but not xml and java files, so continue.
If you don’t see the extensions go through check the configuration

**`Step 2:`**

Now extract this zip apk file in the same folder. Now download dex2jar from this [`link`](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)

and extract it to the same folder. Now open command prompt and change directory to that folder.

Then write `dex2jar classes.dex` and press enter. Now you get `classes.dex.dex2jar` file in the same folder.

Then download java [`de-compiler`](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) from

and now double click on jd-gui and click on open file. Then open `classes.dex.dex2jar` file from that folder. Now you get class files and save all these class files (click on file then click "save all sources" in jd-gui) by src name. Extract that zip file `(classes_dex2jar.src.zip)` and you will get all java files of the application.

At this stage you get java source but the xml files are still unreadable, so continue.

**`Step 3:`**

Now open another new folder and put these files

1. put .apk file which you want to decode
2. download  Apktool for [`windows v1.x`](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool-install-windows-r04-brut1.tar.bz2) And [`Apktool`](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.4.1.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)

install window using google and put in the same folder

1. download framework-res.apk file using google and put in the same folder (Not all apk file need framework-res.apk file)
2. Open a command window
3. Navigate to the root directory of APKtool and type the following command: 
   `apktool if framework-res.apk.`

Above command should result in `Framework installed ...`.

1. apktool d "appName".apk ("appName" denotes application which you want to decode) now you get a file folder in that folder and now you can easily read xml files also.

**`Step 4:`**
Finally we got the `res/` as well as java code of project which is our target at starting.

`Enjoy and happy coding`